# Why is friction in the same direction as someone's motion when walking but opposing when something is rolling?

Tags: friction

So when we walk, static friction helps us move forward since we push backwards on the ground. But why would it be different for a car when the wheels push backward on the ground? Why isn't friction in the same direction as the car's motion?

Comment: It's not different. A driven car wheel pushes backwards on the ground just like your feet do. If you want an explanation into what is wrong about your thought process then you need to explain what is in your mind because your question is based on a false premise but simply states it as though it were fact with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing rolling friction for static friction. The analogous dissipation of energy in a walking person is the collection of mechanical inefficiencies in the walking person, as the musculoskeletal system loads and releases spring like structures,
slides against itself with friction, etc. These could be averaged and expressed as a "force of walking friction" just like rolling friction.  However, while the energy dissipated by rolling is mostly constant over timescales longer than a fraction of a second, the internal forces in the body vary greatly with each passing moment across each step. Consequently, while it makes sense to approximately the energy of rolling as being dissipated by a constant rolling-friction force, walking is thought of in terms of a system whose energy is dissipated by a time averaged mechanical inefficiency.

In either case, the force of static friction points opposite acceleration. Neglecting air resistance, if there is zero acceleration over a given interval, the average of static friction over the same interval is also zero.

Answer (score 1):

Friction opposes the actual or impending motion.

When walking, you push backwards on the ground and friction opposes your foot slipping backwards, so friction acts forwards.

For a car, when it accelerates forwards the tires push backwards on the road hence the force of friction from the road pushes forwards on the tire (Newton's third law) pushing the car forwards.  The force of friction opposes the increased rotation of the tire and pushes the car forwards.

In both cases the force of friction is forwards.

See

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't friction in the same direction as the car's motion?

It is in the same direction as the car's motion, just like it is in the same direction of a person walking or running, provided the friction is static friction. Static friction prevents relative motion, i.e., slipping or sliding, between surfaces. Ignoring air resistance, static friction is the only external horizontal force acting on the person or car and is therefore responsible for either's horizontal acceleration.

There is, however, an upper limit where the maximum possible static friction force is exceeded, and slipping/sliding occurs, at which point the friction changes to kinetic friction. Unlike static friction, kinetic friction acts opposite to the direction of motion, dissipating the energy the walker or car uses to push backwards on the ground that would otherwise be used to cause either to accelerate.

The maximum possible static friction force equals the weight exerted down on the ground by the person's foot or car's tire, times the coefficient of static friction between the foot and ground or tire and ground. If the force exerted backwards by the tire or foot exceeds the maximum static friction force, slipping/sliding occurs.

You know that if a car attempts to accelerate too rapidly, the drive wheel will fruitlessly spin reducing acceleration, depending on the ground conditions. You also know that if you attempt to walk or run too fast on an icy surface, where the coefficient of static friction is low, you will slip on the surface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *'Static friction prevents relative motion, i.e., slipping or sliding, between surfaces'*... *'Ignoring air resistance, static friction is the only external horizontal force acting on the person or car and is therefore responsible for either's horizontal acceleration'* I don't understand the connection between the statements? Can you kindly explain it to me?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I was looking at a horse-cart problem and from the examples I saw the friction between the cart and the ground was backwards, whereas the friction between the horse and the ground is forwards. That's what I find confusing. How can the cart have a backwards frictional force? You might want to look at the horse-cart example for context.

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas I’m sorry but I don’t understand what it is that you don’t understand

Comment: @AshaazImroz It’s because there’s no drive torque applied to the cart wheels. It’s the same for the non drive wheels of the car. They’re dragged along by the drive wheels of the car just like the cart wheels are dragged along by the horse.

Comment: The torque due to Static friction acting backwards on the cart and non drive wheels of the car enable them to turn

Comment: I mean if static friction prevents relative motion then how can it be responsible for horizontal acceleration as it prevents it?

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas Static friction prevents relative motion between the contact point of the wheels and the road, as in skidding, not relative motion (acceleration) between the vehicle and the road. Check out the demonstration of the friction forces (blue arrows) and their effects on the motion of the car as a whole as well as on the wheels, in the simulation for a front wheel drive car in the link below.

Comment: It allows you to see what happens if there is no friction (car doesn’t move at all), friction only on the drive wheels (car accelerates but rear wheels skid without rolling, i.e., there is relative motion between the contact point of  the wheel and the road ) and friction on both wheels (car accelerates and rear wheels turn without skidding, i.e., no relative motion at the contact point.) http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester1/c16_car.html#:~:text=The%20force%20on%20the%20rear,the%20direction%20you%20are%20traveling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have imagined about the friction which stops the car when brakes are applied -then the wheel stops rotating but due to inertia the car still moves forward.

Now instead of rolling the car slides on the ground. Hence the friction opposes the motion and it comes to a stop.

But during motion it's the friction that propels it.